# react Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, api, axios

i am trying to access data from an api but i got this error

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

this is my code

```
return axios.post('http://example.com/api/login', { username: username, password: password }).then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);

        if (response.status === 400 || response.status === 500)
            throw response.data;
        return response.data;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err);

        throw err[1];
    });
```

Backend built with asp.net

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is about your server. Your server does not allow requests which come from different domains. In your case, `http://example.com/api/login` and `http://localhost:3000` are in different domains. You can allow any domain you want in your asp.net code. The following code might be useful for you:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                    "http://www.contoso.com");
            });
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); 

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

For more, you can navigate [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thank you for your concern.. i found this chrome extension solve the problem https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: You can use this just for temporary usage. When you deploy your code to the server, your clients will experience the same error. You must resolve this in your server.

Answer (score -1):

After many hours of searching i found this chrome extension that solve the problem 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf